# What's the quickest way to convert a micro instance to a small instance on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

It is (of course) an EBS backed instance; I would like to see what the impact of having increased CPU power would do for it. What's the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-change-type is the answer

Answer (score 2):

The biggest caveat to this is that an m1.small is a 32-bit machine whereas a t1.micro is a 64-bit machine. Unless you're running a 32-bit AMI on the micro, you won't be able to upgrade to m1.small. You'll have to skip up to the next level where 64-bit is again supported.

Comment: m1.smalls are now available as 64-bit: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Answer (score 0):

Once you change the instance type by stoping the instance and changing instance type, reassociate your elastic IP to that instance. And then:

you need to restart your mysqld and httpd.conf.

sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart

Comment: There's no need to restart mysql/httpd. Stopping the instance handles that just fine.

Comment: I guess it was just mysqld. I had to restart that to get may amazon webserver to work, after I changed the instance type from small to micro

Comment: You may just not have your MySQL set to start on boot.